# Not working Lang Changer in a Class Function PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Hello i try to implent a Language Changer in my Script. 
But in my Class Function it is saying: 
Notice: Undefined variable: lang in ......

I use a if else at begin of my Index.php which decide to includes the correct lang_xxx.php.

And in my lang_xx.php there is Array

```
    /* 
    -----------------
    Language: English
    -----------------
    */

    $lang = array();


$lang['welcome_msg'] = 'Welcome Guest';
```

And echo in my Class then

```
<?php echo $lang['welcome_msg']; ?>
```

So my Question why isnt this working and what is the correct way to implent this?

Its also not working when i include the lang_xx.php File directly in the Class Function.

Comment: try initializing the $lang array as `$lang = array();` before including your lang file.

Comment: It is in the first line of the lang_xx,php i updated my Question.

Comment: at a guess `$lang` is outside the class scope - but not enough code supplied to be sure

Comment: @Dagon yes your right i guess but how can include it within the scope of the Class and all other Files?

Comment: Can you post your class function? Maybe php can't include language file at time.

Comment: @AngelSanchez no sorry that is too much Code to Post here about 2k lines and more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'global' to declare that the variable exists outside of the class.

```
$lang = array();
$lang['welcome_msg'] = 'Welcome Guest';

class Foo {

    function bar(){

        global $lang;  // declare $lang as global, inside the method

        echo $lang[]...

    }

}
```

Comment: Oh Thank You that was the fix.